# Haskell keys-values mapping assignment

Tags: list, haskell, key, concatenation, key-value-store

I have to write a function that given a list of keys finds all values
associated with these keys in a given association list, where a key can have more then one associated values. Therefore the function has to concatenate the results of the lookups for the individual keys.

Here is my code for `lookupOne`:

```
lookupOne :: Int -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupOne x list = [values | (key,values)<-list, x==key]
```

Now I have to write the code for `lookupAll` that will look up for each key of the list and match it to the pair then append the results. I have to follow this:

```
lookupAll :: [Int] -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupAll ... =
```

So I tried many ways to do this but I just cannot figure this out: How does one extract one element of the keys  (because my `lookupOne` only takes an `Int` and not `[Int]`) each time and look it up to the pairs of `(key,value)`. I tried with a map function but it won't work because I don't know how to map a function that uses two arguments (`lookupOne`) as map apparently just takes one list as its argument. I also can't figure out how to pattern match it because apparently `xs` doesn't mean that on the next round it will again only extract one element of `[keys]` Can you please help me comprehend this <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more concise and efficient ways to do this, but sticking to your original implementation you could write it like this:

```
lookupAll :: [Int] -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupAll xs list = [values | (key,values) <- list, key `elem` xs]
```

Comment: And `any (==key)` is also known as `elem key` ;)

Comment: Corrected, I'm not familiar with functions working with list associations, I usually go for `container`s when I need something like it. Thanks @CarstenSchultz

Comment: It was of course correct to begin with, it is only that `key \`elem\` xs` reads more nicely.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `map`, that is fine. Now you already realised that you would need a function that takes only one argument, the key, but `looupOne` takes two. However, the `list` argument will be the same for every invocation, so we can do the following.

```
lookupAll :: [Int] -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupAll xs list = ...
    where f x = lookupOne x list
```

That `f` is the kind of function that you need. Now we can do `map f xs`, however the result will be a list of lists. You can either use `concat` on the result or look at the definition of `concatMap` to see how you could use that.

If you like list comprehensions then you can also try

```
lookupAll xs list = [... | x <- xs, ... <- lookupOne x list, ... <- ...]
```

I leave it to you (since it looks like homework) to figure out the rest.